# Use a variable as index in Tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, indexing

How can I use a variable as index in ".get(startindex [,endindex])" expression, instead of numbers ?
I want something like this:

```
for i in range(1, n):
       a = text.get("i.0", "i.end" )
       b = text.get("i+1.0", "i+1.end" )
```

instead of:

```
   a = text.get("1.0", "1.end" )
   b = text.get("2.0", "2.end" )
   a = text.get("3.0", "3.end" )
   b = text.get("4.0", "4.end" ) etc...
```

In first sequence of code I get "bad text index "i.0" " error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only this information is hard to say what the purpose of this, but directly answering your question you can use **string interpolation** [python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) such as .format method:

```
for i in range(1, n):
       a = text.get("{0}.0".format(i), "{0}.end".format(i) )
       b = text.get("{0}.0".format(i + 1), "{0}.end".format(i + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have 3 way string format with python**

```
text.get("%d.0"%(i + 1), "%.end"%(i)) # 1 
text.get("{0}.0".format(i), "{0}.end".format(i) ) # 2
text.get(f"{i+1}.0", f"{i}.end") # 3
```